# How to export pandas dataframe to file so it can be open using pandas dan pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I've read both `pandas.read_csv` and `pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv` documentation and it seems that PySpark side doesn't have `doublequote` parameter so the quote character inside field is escaped using escape character and pandas doubling quote character to show that qoute character is inside the field.

This can be solve by set parameter `doubleqoute=False` and `escapechar='\\'` in `pandas.to_csv` and set parameter `multiLine=True` in `pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv`.

But, after I set those parameter to `pandas.to_csv` and then tried to `pandas.read_csv` by using same parameter. I got error showing that this line have 4 field when expect 3 field.

```
1242,"I see him, I know him \",an_username
1243,"I think I'm good now",another_username
```

I think the reason why the error occur is because the second field of first line contains `\` as the last character and pandas reads it as escaping character `"` and think that the second field isn't end there. Is there any way to solve this beside remove `\` character?

This is the example script to get the error

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

f = StringIO()
pd.DataFrame({'class':['y','y','n'],
              'text':['I am fine','I saw him, I knew him \\','I think, I am good now'],
              'value':['username','an_username','another_username']})\
  .to_csv(f,doublequote=False,escapechar='\\',index=False)
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
f.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(f,doublequote=False,escapechar='\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same but didn't get this problem. Please check the below tried code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('d.csv', doublequote=False)

data_1 = pd.read_csv('d.csv')
print(data_1)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1242, I see him, I know him, True]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1242, I see him, I know him, True]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, 1242, I see him, I know him, True]
Index: []
```

Hope, this may helps you.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I get the reasons why it's getting the error. I'm gonna edit my question